# Makefile is always 'up to date' while files have been changed

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile to compile several fortran files, most of which are module files. Whenever I changed the module file and initiate make command, the make says:

```
make: `PRM' is up to date.
```

PRM is the executable name. No such problem when I changed the main file. Another problem is that sometimes I also get:

```
make: m2c: Command not found
```

error. My makefile looks like:

```
.SUFFIXES: .f90

F90        = pgf90
NETCDF_DIR = /opt/netcdf

F90_FLAGS  = -Mbackslash -Mlarge_arrays

LIBS            = -L$(NETCDF_DIR)/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf
INCLUDE_MODULES = -I$(NETCDF_DIR)/include

VPATH = /path/FORTRAN

util_module = \
  precmod.o \
  strings.o

EXEC = PRM
OBJS = \
       ${util_module} \
       mo_date.o \
       mo_utils.o \
       module_metcro_lib.o \
       module_plumerise1.o \
       module_finn_lib.o \
       main_plm.o


${EXEC} : ${OBJS}
        ${F90} -o $@ ${OBJS} ${LIBS}

.f90.o:
        ${F90} -c ${F90_FLAGS} ${INCLUDE_MODULES} $<

clean:
        rm -f ${EXEC} ${OBJS} *.mod
```

thanks for answering!

Comment: Your target .f90.o seems strange. Maybe you can replace it with ${OBJS}:%.o:%.f90

Comment: Seemingly it works. the .f90.o came from some book. I don't know why it would cause problems

Comment: What happens when you modify (or `touch`) `main_plm.f90`, then "make main_plm.o"?